# How can I get MAC address in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, networking, wireless, ethernet

I tried with several commands, but it does not work, please see the command:

```
khalilullah@khalilullah-W65-67SZ:~$ sudo ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:12080 (12.0 KB)  TX bytes:12080 (12.0 KB)

khalilullah@khalilullah-W65-67SZ:~$ nmcli device show enp3s0|grep -i hw
Error: Device 'enp3s0' not found.

khalilullah@khalilullah-W65-67SZ:~$ nmcli device show enp3s0 | grep -i hw
Error: Device 'enp3s0' not found.

khalilullah@khalilullah-W65-67SZ:~$ nmcli device show wlp4s0 | grep -i hw
Error: Device 'wlp4s0' not found.


khalilullah@khalilullah-W65-67SZ:~$ sudo ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:164 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:12080 (12.0 KB)  TX bytes:12080 (12.0 KB)

khalilullah@khalilullah-W65-67SZ:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
```

How can I get MAC?

Comment: If `ifconfig -a` does not return any Ethernet device, the device is not connected or the driver is missing. Take a look into `dmesg` and search for issues with your network hardware

Comment: where did you get `enp3s0` from?

Answer (score 8):

You can find the MAC address for your network devices with the terminal command:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

The MAC address is called 'serial,' like this, for example:

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection I217-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 04
       serial: 11:22:33:44:aa:bb
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       <snip>
```

If your devices do not appear in `ifconfig` then they are probably not yet claimed by any drivers.

Comment: Hi, Is serial MAC here?